# Edit list of entries using Python

Tags: python, list

My script so far:

```
#DogReg v1.0
import time
Students = ['Mary', 'Matthew', 'Mark', 'Lianne' 'Spencer'
            'John', 'Logan', 'Sam', 'Judy', 'Jc', 'Aj'  ]

print("1. Add Student")
print("2. Delete Student")
print("3. Edit Student")                             
print("4. Show All Students")
useMenu = input("What shall you do? ")
if(useMenu != "1" and useMenu != "2" and useMenu != "3" and useMenu != "4"):
    print("Invalid request please choose 1, 2, 3, or 4.")
elif(useMenu == "1"):
    newName = input("What is the students name? ")
    Students.append(newName)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(str(newName) + " added.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(Students)
elif(useMenu == "2"):
    remStudent = input("What student would you like to remove? ")
    Students.remove(remStudent)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(str(remStudent) + " has been removed.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(Students)
elif(useMenu == "3"):
```

So I'm trying to be able to let the user input a name they want to edit and change it.

I tried looking up the function for editing list entries and I haven't found one I'm looking for.

Comment: It looks like you know how to remove an item from the list and how to add an item to the list, which is basically what editing is. Why don't you work with that?

Comment: can you be a bit more clear exactly what is the problem here, whether you find your approach not appropriate or you are facing some problem in the script itself

Comment: There's no need to include `I need help a little help. (Is this out of my league right now?` in the title. Also, your problem isn't clear. Please elaborate more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
elif(useMenu == "3"):

    oldName = input("What student would you like to edit? ")

    if oldName in Students:

        index = Students.index(oldName)
        newName = input("What is the student's new name? ")
        Students[index] = newName
        time.sleep(1)
        print(str(oldName) + " has been edited to " + str(newName))
        time.sleep(1)

    else: 

       print('Student' + oldName + 'not found!')

    print(Students)
```

with output:

```
1. Add Student
2. Delete Student
3. Edit Student
4. Show All Students
What shall you do? '3'
What student would you like to edit? 'Mary'
What is the student's new name? 'Marry'
Mary has been edited to Marry
['Marry', 'Matthew', 'Mark', 'LianneSpencerJohn', 'Logan', 'Sam', 'Judy', 'Jc', 'Aj']
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the user wants to change `'Mary'` to `'Maria'`:

```
student_old = 'Mary'
student_new = 'Maria'
change_index = Students.index(student_old)
Students[change_index] = student_new
```

Note that you will have to add proper error handling - for example, if the user asks for modifying `'Xavier'` who is not in your list, you will get a `ValueError`.